# Can I ask questions regarding the quality of my own design here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I have just designed a system which aids the interaction of AI agents with an environment. However, I am not sure whether my design is efficient, so I would like people here to point out my mistakes.

I don't plan only to ask "is my design a good one?", but put it in the context of the well-defined OOP paradigm, which most of you probably understand much better than me and could help me point out concrete problems.

Is Stack Overflow the right place to ask such a question?

Comment: see detailed breakdown of SE sites given here: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

Answer (score 3):

If it's a design question then [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is probably a better place to ask.

Though the same rules about the question being **specific** and **answerable** apply there as they do on Stack Overflow. If your question is just "which is better?" or "is this a good design?" then it will likely get closed as not constructive.

Comment: The question could be deemed as too localized, but the answers to it could help others in the future. Also, in a well defined context, I doubt it wouldn't be answerable...

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an opinion on your code/design, you should ask the question at 
[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#questions).